# In Python, how should I implement an Inherited class with the exact same properties and methods as the Parent class?

Tags: python, object, inheritance

I'm doing a project with Python and have defined a base class called `Encoder`:

```
class Encoder:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def encode(self, text):
        ...
```

Now I want to create two child classes called `RotatingEncoder` and `StaticEnocder` that inherit from this class.

```
class RotatingEncoder(Encoder):
    def __init__(self, rotor_size=26):
        ...
        # do stuff
        ...
        super().__init__()

    def encode(self, text):
        ...
        # do stuff
        ...
        return super().encode(text)
```

Defining `RotatingEnocder` is easy, but I have a few doubts regarding how to define `StaticEnocder`.

A `StaticEncoder` works exactly like an `Encoder` object. All its properites and methods are the same. But how do I define it? Here are two methods I thought of:

```
# Method A
class StaticEncoder(Encoder):
    pass


# Method B
class StaticEncoder(Encoder):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def encode(self, text):
        return super().encode(text)
```

Should I use one of these, or any other method? I would like my code to be as readable, and Pythonic, as possible

Comment: There's no point overriding methods just to have them do the same as they would have done anyway. So out of those two options, method A.

Comment: Alternatively make `Encoder` an [_abstract class_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) or [_protocol_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) which `StaticEncoder` and `RotatingCoder` implement.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you! I'm going with the abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

If it is absolutely required that `Encoder` be a non-abstract base class, Method A is best:

```py
class StaticEncoder(Encoder):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm making `Encoder` an abstract class instead.

Comment: @NandishGupta, what about if it is an abstract base class? What would be the best method, then?